# Define $f(y)=d(x_0,y)$, prove that $f$ is continuous.

Tags: general-topology, analysis, continuity

Consider a metric space $(X,d)$ and some $x_o \in X$.

Define function $f_{x_0}(y)=d(x_0,y), $ which is in $\text{R}$. Show that the function is continuous.

Here's what I've tried:

According to definition, we want to find a $\delta>0$ such that: whenever $d(x,y)<\delta$, we have $|d(x_0,x)-d(x_0,y)|<\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon>0$. Then I just got stuck.

It seems like if we have $d(x_0,x)+d(x_0,y)<\epsilon$, then we would end up with $|d(x_0,x)-d(x_0,y)|<\epsilon$. But it wouldn't work if we simply take $\epsilon=\delta$.

Any idea?

Comment: By use the triangle inequality: $|d(x,y)-d(y,z)|\leq d(x,z)$.

Comment: @Misakov Did you try to apply it to both and see at what you arrive and when is it useful?

Comment: $|d(x_0,x)-d(x_0,y)|\leq d(x,y)$ and just take $\delta=\epsilon$

Comment: @AlfredChern That's where I got lost. Mind explain how can we get that expression?

Comment: @Misakov: $\delta$ is depend on $\epsilon$, exactly, $\delta=\delta(\epsilon)$ is a function of $\epsilon$.

Comment: @AlfredChern I mean how do you get $|d(x_0,x)−d(x_0,y)|≤d(x,y)$?

Comment: @Misakov: That's just the triangle inequality in metric space.

Comment: @AlfredChern The version my textbooks has is $d(x,z)\le d(x,y)+d(y,z)$...lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem

By the triangle inequality:

$$d(x_0,x)\leq d(x_0,y)+d(x,y)$$ and $$d(x_0,y)\leq d(x_0,x)+d(x,y)$$
so $$-d(x,y)\leq d(x_0,x)-d(x_0,y)\leq d(x,y)$$
i.e.$$|d(x_0,x)-d(x_0,y)|\leq d(x,y)$$
Exactly, $|d(x,z)-d(y,z)|\leq d(x,y)$ is equivalent to the triangle inequality.

$\forall\epsilon>0,\exists\delta=\epsilon>0$, s.t. whenever $d(x,y)<\delta$, we have $|d(x_0,x)-d(x_0,y)|\leq d(x,y)<\delta=\epsilon$.